# command line filtering of Unicode block

Tags: perl, unicode, grep

I've been trying for a couple hours to create a conceptually trivial filter that I can use on the command line, without success.  The task is to filter out all lines containing Hangul Jamo characters, while retaining all other lines (which may contain ASCII, characters in the Hangul Syllable block, etc.).

So for example if the input was

```
 foo
 ᅤᆨ
 간
```

the output would contain the first and third lines, but not the second, since the second line contains Jamo characters.  (The above is not meant to be real Korean, just a simple test case.)

I'm very disappointed with the Gnu grep utility (version 2.20).  I would have thought the ff. would work:

```
grep -Pv '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]'
```

but instead I get the error message `grep: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large`.  (The \u1100 syntax, which is the actual Perl syntax, simply isn't supported.)

(I do notice that our version 2.20 is rather old.  If someone tries the above with a newer version of grep, and it works, I'll certainly consider that an answer--and I'll get our IT folks to upgrade!)

I tried sed, but didn't get any further.  (Sorry, I don't remember exactly what sed commands I tried, but sed's support for Unicode blocks doesn't seem any better than grep's.)

Finally, I tried perl (v5.16.3):

```
 perl -ne 'print unless /[\u1100-\u11ff]/'
```

This at least succeeds in eliminating the Jamo lines while retaining the Hangul Syllable lines, but it also eliminates the ASCII lines, which I don't want to do.  I also would have thought one of the ff. would work:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /\p{InHangul_Jamo}/'
perl -ne 'print unless /\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}/'
```

but neither appears to have any effect.  (Afaik, I shouldn't have to have a `.*` on each side of the `\p{...}`, but I tried that too; no luck.)

Locale: in case it matters, I have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

I'm sure I could do this in Python, but I'd like to understand why neither grep nor perl seems to work, because they'd be a lot simpler.  (And if I'm right about the Gnu utilities having poor Unicode support, why that is...and when it will be fixed.  It's not like Unicode is new!)  Of course I realize the problem may be that I'm not holding my mouth right when I try, but if so, it would be nice for grep at least to have better documentation on Unicode usage.  Right now the documentation for `grep -P` says "This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features."  And it seems to have been that way roughly forever.

Comment: Re "*The \u1100 syntax, which is the actual Perl syntax, simply isn't supported.*" `\u1234` is used by JavaScript and JSON, not Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode inputs, encode outputs. If the encoding in question is UTF-8, the command-line switch `-CSD` will come in useful.

```
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/\p{Block: Jamo}/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/\p{Blk=Jamo}/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/\p{InJamo}/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\N{U+1100}-\N{U+11FF}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]/'
grep -vP '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]'
```

You might want to add the `Hangul_Jamo_Extended_A`, `Hangul_Jamo_Extended_B` and `Hangul_Compatibility_Jamo` blocks.

```
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo_Extended_A}\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo_Extended_B}\p{Block: Hangul_Compatibility_Jamo}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\p{Block: Jamo}\p{Block: JamoExtA}\p{Block: JamoExtB}\p{Block: CompatJamo}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\p{Blk=Jamo}\p{Blk=JamoExtA}\p{Blk=JamoExtB}\p{Blk=CompatJamo}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\p{InJamo}\p{InJamoExtA}\p{InJamoExtB}\p{InCompatJamo}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\N{U+1100}-\N{U+11FF}\N{U+A960}-\N{U+A97F}\N{U+D7B0}-\N{U+D7FF}\N{U+3130}-\N{U+318F}]/'
perl -CSD -ne'print if !/[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{A960}-\x{A97F}\x{D7B0}-\x{D7FF}\x{3130}-\x{318F}]/'
grep -vP '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{A960}-\x{A97F}\x{D7B0}-\x{D7FF}\x{3130}-\x{318F}]'
```

---

Let's look at your failed attempts.

- > *`grep -Pv '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]'`*

  Actually, this one should work, and it does for me.

  ```
  $ perl -CSD -e'print "abc\nd\x{1100}f\nghi\n"' | od -t x1
  0000000 61 62 63 0a 64 e1 84 80 66 0a 67 68 69 0a
  0000016

  $ perl -CSD -e'print "abc\nd\x{1100}f\nghi\n"' | grep -Pv '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]'
  abc
  ghi

  $ grep --version | head -1
  grep (GNU grep) 2.16
  ```

  I do get your error on an older machine with `grep (GNU grep) 2.10`.
- > *`perl -ne'print unless /\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}/'`*

  You didn't get any matches from `/\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}/` because you were matching against encoded text (UTF-8 bytes, chars in the range 00..FF) instead of decoded text (Unicode Code Points, chars in the range 00000..10FFFF).
- > *`perl -ne 'print unless /\p{InHangul_Jamo}/'`*

  `\p{Block: X}`, `\p{Blk=X}` and `\p{InX}` are equivalent.
- > *`perl -ne'print unless /[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]/'`*

  `[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}]` is equivalent to `\p{Block: Hangul_Jamo}`.
- > *`perl -ne'print unless /[\u1100-\u11ff]/'`*

  You got too many matches since `\u` in double-quoted string literals and in regex pattern literals titlecases the next character. (e.g. `"\uxyx"` is equivalent to `"Xyz"`.)

  As such, `[\u1100-\u11ff]` is equivalent to `[01f]`.

Comment: The -CSD option is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: As for the grep issue, using v2.20 I verified today that I (still) get that error msg.  Perhaps there's a bug that was introduced between 2.16 and 2.20; I have a later version on my home PC, and will check how it works there tonight.  And I accepted your answer.  (BTW, I know about the other Jamo blocks, but I wanted to keep my question simple.)

Comment: More likely, it's dependent of the version of a library used by grep.

Comment: Hmm, a run-time (dynamic/ shared) library, rather than a compile-time (static) library, right?  How would I find out what library grep is using?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe [tag:PCRE]?

Comment: You're right!  the error msg ("character value in \u.... sequence is too large") comes from pcre, see 2/3 of the way down https://pcre.org/pcre.txt  We have pcre version 8.32 of 2012-11-30

Comment: I confirmed last night that grep issues the same error msg ("...sequence is too large") on my home computer.  The version of grep there is 2.25 (Linux-in-windows, Ubuntu bash etc., fully updated).  I don't know what version of the pcre lib I have there.  I don't have the time to further pursue it, since the perl solution works for me, I just want again to voice my disappointment at the state of Unicode support in the Gnu/Linux utilities...

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, this is my own jamo filter in gnu-grep :

noJamo is an alias for

```
ggrep -vP '[\x{1100}-\x{11FF}
            \x{A960}-\x{A97F}
            \x{D7B0}-\x{D7FF}
            \x{3130}-\x{318F}]'
```

However, if you only care about the core Jamo set that maps to `11,172 syllables`, and don't mind using something other than grep, then this should be extremely fast :

```
\341\204[\200-\222]|
\341\205[\241-\265]|
\341\206[\250-\277]|\341\207[\200-\202]
```

if you add up the octals in each line, they're exactly 19 cho in row 1, 21 jung in row 2, and 28 jong in row 3.

I did a quick benchmark with a synthetic 5.55 GB .txt file containing lines that add up to some 4.3 GB.

And this regex's filtering throughput was some 1.55 GB/sec, practically at the limit of my SSD I/O.

```
(time (pvE0 < jamotest000001.txt| 
       mawk2 'BEGIN{ FS=ORS }

  /\341(\204[\200-\222]|
        \205[\241-\265]|
        \206[\250-\277]|
        \207[\200-\202] )/' 

| pvE9 | xxh128sum))| ecp; 

 
      in0: 5.55GiB 0:00:03 [1.55GiB/s] [1.55GiB/s]
  [=================>] 100%            
     out9: 4.29GiB 0:00:03 [1.20GiB/s] [1.20GiB/s]
  [                      <=>          ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < jamotest000001.txt | mawk2  | pvE 0.1 out9 | xxh128sum; ) 

 3.70s user 2.73s system 178% cpu 3.597 total

f4ef119214a3c39c7c560ad24491b96c  stdin
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind!  BTW, you wrote ggrep, rather than grep.  I can't find much about ggrep, even on its github page, except that maybe it's a gui interface to grep.

Comment: sorry i should've clarified. it's just how i call my gnu-grep, since i'm on a BSD-descendent system, and its BSD-derived grep stinks like no tomorrow, so i primarily use the gnu one instead.

Comment: ps : do you actually need all those ancient forms of jamo, or just the modern ones ? cuz you can trim that search set to just U+1100-1112, 1161-1175, 11A8-11C2. if that's too complex, trim latter to U+1161-U+11C2. EVEN faster shortcut : there's absolutely nothing else relevant in that space 4 first 2 uc bytes, simply filtering by \341 [\204-\207] get u everything you need. I created a 16.9 GB synthetic file filled to the brim w/ jamo. 2-byte inclusion-filter has throughput rate of 2.58 GiB/s; exclusion filter 3.35 GiB/s, quite insane 4 something that doesn't even use more than 1 cpu core.

Comment: Re those ancient forms of jamo: my original post was four years ago, and I confess I've forgotten why I needed that.  I think I was doing conversion, but my memory is... let's just say my brain's RAM is not what it once was.  Or its hard drive is filling up.  Or something.  At any rate, I've run into similar issues when trying to search for other Unicode characters, so I do refer to this query some when I get stuck.

Comment: no worries. a lot of times i try not to be strictly using Unicode's specs in defining my filtering and querying needs. case in point : half-width jamos - they're in U+FFA1-FFDC, but those get listed in the block named "Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms", but at the same time, if you just include the full HW+FW block, then it would also include far too much, including wide-ASCII and half-width katakana, hardly desirable if your objective is just Jamo